# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pathfinding'

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and noticed that the code on https://pypi.org/project/pathfinding/ does not work on colab, but works on my personal spyder. This is the code and was wondering why it works in some places and not the others. I've noticed this with a couple other libraries too. Any help is appreciated. The error is the title.

```
    from pathfinding.core.diagonal_movement import DiagonalMovement
    from pathfinding.core.grid import Grid
    from pathfinding.finder.a_star import AStarFinder
```

Code:

```
    matrix = [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
    grid = Grid(matrix=matrix)
    
    start = grid.node(0, 0)
    end = grid.node(2, 2)
    
    finder = AStarFinder(diagonal_movement=DiagonalMovement.always)
    path, runs = finder.find_path(start, end, grid)
    
    print('operations:', runs, 'path length:', len(path))
    print(grid.grid_str(path=path, start=start, end=end))
```

Comment: Did you install pathfinding in the colab?  It's not a built-in module, so it has to be installed using `pip install pathfinding`

Comment: @nigh_anxiety it was just that. And I needed an exclamation point in the front. Thanks.